# How do I dynamically create a callable method generated at runtime?

Tags: python-3.x, dynamically-generated

Here is a simplified example that I am using to practice:

```
import sys

def generate_subprocess_runner(funcname: str=None, cred_path: str=None):
    if funcname is None:
        raise ValueError("\"funcname\" cannot be None.")

    if cred_path is None:
        raise ValueError("\"cred_path\" cannot be None.")

    #This function is simple.
    str_buff = []
    str_buff.append("def {:s}():\n".format(funcname))
    str_buff.append("\ttry:\n")
    str_buff.append("\t\tprint(\"{:s}\")\n".format(
            cred_path
        ))
    str_buff.append("\t\texit(0)\n")
    str_buff.append("\texcept BaseException as exception:\n")
    str_buff.append("\t\texit(1)\n")

    str_func = ''.join(str_buff)
    exec(str_func)
```

What I hope to achieve is to pass the generated Callable to multiprocessing.Process().
The real code will be for unit testing, wherein we set an environment variable and evaluate code that should be checking that variable for anomalies.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I suspect is a naive way. I just add the generated function to the current module:

```
import sys
def generate_subprocess_runner(funcname: str=None, cred_path: str=None):
    if funcname is None:
        raise ValueError("\"funcname\" cannot be None.")

    if cred_path is None:
        raise ValueError("\"cred_path\" cannot be None.")

    #This function is simple. It returns different error codes
    #depending on which exception (if any) is raised.
    str_buff = []
    str_buff.append("def {:s}():\n".format(funcname))
    str_buff.append("\ttry:\n")
    str_buff.append("\t\tfor i in range(0,100000):\n")
    str_buff.append("\t\t\tprint(\"{:s}\")\n".format(
            cred_path
        ))
    str_buff.append("\texcept BaseException as exception:\n")
    str_buff.append("\t\texit(1)\n")
    str_buff.append("mod = sys.modules[__name__]\n")
    str_buff.append("mod.__dict__[\"{:s}\"]={:s}".format(funcname,funcname))

    str_func = ''.join(str_buff)
    exec(str_func)
```